# AngularJS : Change md-option depending on input checkbox

Tags: angularjs

How do I change the value of an md-select based on an md-checkbox?

If my checkbox is checked I display the value 1 of my select otherwise I display the value 2.

```
<div ng-form="mailForm">
     <md-checkbox ng-model="company.email" ng-disabled="!editMode">
            {{ 'company.email' | translate }}
     </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

```
<div>
        <label>{{ 'company.send' | translate }}</label>
        <md-select ng-model="form.sendingModeUpdate" ng-disabled="!editMode" placeholder="{{ 'company.sendingMode' | translate }}"
                   ng-change="onChangeSendingMode()">
            <md-option ng-repeat="sendingMode in parameters.SENDING_MODE" ng-value="sendingMode" ng-selected="company.sendingMode == sendingMode.code" >
                {{ sendingMode.property1 }}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to you are using models I would fire an onChange event everytime you change your checkbox in order to change the value on the md-select using the model "form.sendingModeUpdate", so I would do something as the following:

```
<div ng-form="mailForm">
     <md-checkbox ng-model="company.email" ng-disabled="!editMode" ng-change="onChangeCompanyEmail()">
            {{ 'company.email' | translate }}
     </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

In your component .js create the event function

```
$scope.onChangeCompanyEmail = function() {
                                 $scope.form.sendingModeUpdate = $scope.company.email ? 1 : 2; //1 and 2 should be replaced with the values of your md-select
                              }
```

Then in the initialization of your form you need to do the comparison of company.email in order to put a value for sendingModeUpdate as the same way as in the onChangeCompanyEmail function.